# How do someone calculate the wavelength of a receding object in space?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, redshift

Is it possible to calculate the original wavelength of a star, say, which is subjected to cosmological redshift?
if yes, how?

Looking at the answers I think I need to edit it to be more specific.
Suppose I'm observing a galaxy, I observe it's spectrum. From the doppler shift I indeed can calculate its velocity. Now say, z>6 then you can see it's not any sort of normal redshift, rather its the cosmological redshift.

Now my question is, from z value I'll get the a(expansion factor ), it's distance and hence how old the radiation is, but can I calculate its original wavelength and hence its temperature.

how do I calculate these??

Answer (score 0):

A pattern of Fraunhofer lines can identify atoms. The ratio of frequencies for pairs of lines from a pattern for a particular atom is independent of redshift. The ratio of a frequency of a line from a distance source compared with the known laboratory frequency is the observed redshift which has three components: (a) Doppler, (b) gravitational, and (c) cosmological. If you want more details, please ask.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the redshift equation to find the original wavelength if you know the velocity that the star is moving away from you.
[image]
If you do not know the recession velocity you can utilize the oscillation of the star. If the star is stably oscillating there should be periods when you see a blue shift and periods where you see a red shift. By comparing the blue shift and red shift you can pull out an original wavelength. ( This will depend on the type of oscillation and our perspective to this oscillation.)
Hope that helps be warned I don't study astro physics. I am geared more towards mechanical engineering and applied physics, but I hope this helps :).

Comment: We can use spectroscopy to determine original wavelength(s) without knowing the velocity of the star

Comment: Please look at the question now.